# group numbers using sed

Tags: sed, numbers, concatenation, grouping

would you help me to find a simple sed command to group numbers together:

so: `01 02` would become `0102`.
But `A01 02` will stay identical such as `01 A02`, or `01 02A`.

I have tried this:

```
echo "01 02 A01 02" | sed -E 's/([0-9]+) +([0-9]+)/\1\2/g'
```

But I have as result `0102 A0102` which is not correct.
it should be `0102 A01 02`.

Any help?
Note: ChatGPT could not find the right solution to this problem!

Answer (score 2):

You can match if something before the number is a space or beginning of the line.

```
echo "01 02 A01 02" | sed -E 's/((^| )[0-9]+) +([0-9]+)/\1\3/g'
```

To replace all instances, you basically have to loop until all
replacements are done. I think we can be smart and use `t` command

```
echo "01 02 03 A01 02" | sed -E ':a;s/((^| )[0-9]+) +([0-9]+)/\1\3/g;ta'
```

But more readable would be:

```
echo "01 02 03 A01 02" | sed -E ':a;/((^| )[0-9]+) +([0-9]+)/{s//\1\3/g;ba}'
```

Comment: I like this approach. I didn't come up with the idea to use an "or" with "^" and "<space>" ;-)

Comment: echo "A01 02 526 fdsfsd 5464 45645 45" | sed -E 's/((^| )[0-9]+) +([0-9]+)/\1\3/g' will result "A01 02526 fdsfsd 546445645 45" but it should give "A01 02526 fdsfsd 54644564545"

Comment: And? You mean the last numbers are split? `g` flag doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: `echo "01 02A" | sed ...` returns `0102A`.

Answer (score 2):

You could as well use word boundary to match only groups that start with a certain char, also you can be even more precise on how many digits are expected:

```
echo "01 02 A01 02" | sed -E 's/\b([0-9]{2})\s+([0-9]{2})/\1\2/g'
```

Comment: `echo "01 02A" | sed ...` returns `0102A`

Comment: @WalterA just needs terminating boundary as well:  `sed -E 's/\b([0-9]+) +([0-9]+)\b/\1\2/g'` which as it turns out is OP with boundaries added.  They're great because they're nonconsuming.   Although the rest of the match is consuming, so you will process pairs and fail to join triples etc.

Answer (score 0):

The OP with word boundary markers (`\b`) on either end of the match would work to join all pairs of digit strings, but because the match is consuming and there is no nonconsuming lookahead, you need to use a loop of some sort in sed to deal with joining triples and other tuples.  (So, it's hard to do `01 23 45 A` ==> `012345 A`)

However the easiest way to get perl-like regex extensions is to use perl's stream processing modes:

`perl -pe 's/\b([0-9]+) +(?=[0-9]+)\b/\1\2/g' input-file`

The `?=` simply marks the second capture group as a lookahead, so it's nonconsuming, and the next match can begin at the beginning of that group.

Perl also supports `\d` for "digit" and using `$1` instead of `\1` is more perly:

`perl -pe 's/\b(\d+)\s+(?=\d+)\b/$1$2/g' input-file`

Where `perl -p` is like sed and `perl -n` is like `sed -n`.  Perl also supports all sorts of other syntax but clearly one of the design goals was using it just like sed.